# Can the Vice President vote themselves into positions of power?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution, separation-of-powers

With the retirement of Stephen Breyer from the Supreme Court, and Biden's promise to nominate a Black woman to fill the vacancy, some of the most far-fetched speculation about the nominee has involved Kamala Harris. The Senate is currently evenly split with Kamala Harris's vote breaking the tie.

If, in this hypothetical, Biden actually nominated her, and the Senate was tied when voting to confirm her, would she be able to cast the tie-breaking vote to put herself on the bench?

Does a judicial nominee's power to do this not infringe upon the separation of powers? Or, if it does not, how is the Senate providing ‘advice and consent’ when a judicial nominee is ultimately the one who gives their consent when the Senate can't agree without the VP?

A similar question arises when there's an Electoral College tie, and the Senate is tied, which would allow the incumbent VP to vote themselves back into power if they're standing for re-election.

Does the Constitution permit such a flagrant power grab?

Comment: How is this different from a situation in which a senator from a majority faction votes to confirm themselves, after getting nominated?  It's not a power grab because their vote is one of majority votes and they need to be nominated first anyway.

Comment: This is more about conflicts of interest, not separation of powers, and there's little in the constitution about COI (although VPOTUS doesn't preside when POTUS is being impeached). And POTUS can avoid this simply by not nominating VPOTUS or a senator.

Comment: @Barmar Isn’t the separation of the powers all about preventing conflicts of interest though?

Comment: @Tolga I don't think so. Suppose we just had Congress, with no Presidential veto or judicial review. The requirement for all the congressmen to agree on legislation would prevent individual conflicts of interest from overwhelming the decisions.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but that is a government with only a legislative branch, so there is no need for it to be separate from another branch. Any government which wishes to operate with three different branches requires a separation of powers to avoid a conflict of interest.

Comment: @Tolga I think you're using "conflict of interest" in a different way than usual. It doesn't mean conflict between the branches, it means a conflict between the needs of the governed and those making the decisions.

Comment: @Barmar Of which there would be if, for example, a legislator was also a judge. If someone who helped draft a statute was also the same person to interpret it in a judicial-review case, in which the plaintiff argued that the statute infringed upon their constitutional rights, what are the odds they'd find a law they helped create, thus almost certainly want to stay on the statute books, unconstitutional? Would they not already have a bias in favour of the defendant? Isn't that a conflict between the needs of the governed and the interests of the decision-maker here, or am I missing something?

Comment: The need of the governed would be to have an impartial decision-maker when interpreting the law, while the interests of the decision-maker would be to keep a law they created, felt was a good piece of legislation that society required and was absolutely valid.

Comment: @Tolga That's not what we usually mean by conflict of interest. We usually mean things like passing a law that benefits a company that you own, or a judge ruling on a case involving a relative.

Comment: @Barmar That's because that's the kind of conflict of interest that is still possible in a system that does its best to maintain a separation of powers. You're not thinking in hypothetical terms. However, I'd be quite surprised if you thought a judge wouldn't have a conflict of interest if they didn't help draft the law(s) they were going to make a ruling on in a hypothetical system where powers were fused. Why did two Law Lords who voted on the Hunting Act 2004 disqualify themselves from any cases involving it that reached the Appellate Committee of the House of Lords?

Answer (score 18):

The [US Constitution Art. 1 §3 cl. 4](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S3-C4-1/ALDE_00001111/) says

> The Vice President of the United States shall be President of the
> Senate, but shall have no Vote, unless they be equally divided.

No clause of the Constitution limits how a person can vote in the Senate (or the House). Congress has not enacted any legislation that addresses this question, and nothing in the Constitution empowers Congress to limit the right to vote.

Art 1 §5 cl. 2 says

> Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings, punish its
> Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two
> thirds, expel a Member.

That is, the Senate can set up rules for how it will conduct business. The Senate is *not* empowered to exclude a member's right to vote, they with a supermajority they can expel a member (or convict and remove a vice-president, given an impeachment from the House). It should also be remembered that the VP is not a member of the Senate, the VP has a limited right to vote which is granted by the Constitution, and which cannot be taken away except by constitutional amendment. Harris would therefore be empowered to vote for herself, under the tie-breaker clause.

Comment: To be nit-picky... The Senate cannot impeach the VP, only the house can (an impeachment is like an indictment for _Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors_).  Once a VP (or other officer) is impeached, then the Senate holds a trial and it can vote to remove the offender from office and to possibly bar the offender from ever holding office again.

Answer (score 11):

Separation of powers is a guideline, or perhaps it might better be called a design goal, of the US federal government, not an unbreachable rule. Strictly speaking, confirmation of executive appointments by the Senate is a violation of the separation of powers. Read *The Federalist* for a detailed explanation of the complex way in which powers of the three main departments are separated in some matters and intermixed in others, and of the reasons why the thee authors, all key members of the convention that drafted the Constitution, thought this wise.

Specifically in No 51 of *The Federalist*, it is stated:

> In order to lay a due foundation for that separate and distinct exercise of the different powers of government, which to a certain extent is admitted on all hands to be essential to the preservation of liberty, it is evident that each department should have a will of its own; and consequently should be so constituted that the members of each should have as little agency as possible in the appointment of the members of the others. Were this principle rigorously adhered to, it would require that all the appointments for the supreme executive, legislative, and judiciary magistracies should be drawn from the same fountain of authority, the people, through channels having no communication whatever with one another. Perhaps such a plan of constructing the several departments would be less difficult in practice than it may in contemplation appear. Some difficulties, however, and some additional expense would attend the execution of it. **Some deviations, therefore, from the principle must be admitted.** In the constitution of the judiciary department in particular, it might be inexpedient to insist rigorously on the principle: first, because peculiar qualifications being essential in the members, the primary consideration ought to be to select that mode of choice which best secures these qualifications; secondly, because the permanent tenure by which the appointments are held in that department, must soon destroy all sense of dependence on the authority conferring them. [*Emphasis added.*]

The [Wikipedia article about this essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federalist_No._51) states:

> Federalist No. 51 addresses means by which appropriate checks and balances can be created in government and also advocates a separation of powers within the national government. The idea of checks and balances is a crucial part of the modern U.S. system of government.

As to the specific questions:

1. In the unlikely event that a US President nominated the sitting vice-President to the US Supreme Court (it has never been done), if the senate split 50-50 on confirming such a nomination, the VP could indeed vote to confirm that nomination, although for political reasons, the VP might abstain (and a tie vote loses in the Senate).
2. If no one person has 270 electoral votes for VP, the senate chooses **from among the top two electoral vote getters** for VP.  If the senate split equally between those two, the then-sitting VP could vote to break the tie.

   If and only if such a VP was one of the top 2 (presumably if running for reelection), then such a VP could vote for himself or herself.  I would not call a vote to choose a person as VP who was nominated, was one of the top-2 electoral vote getters, **and** was the recipient of the votes of 50 senators a "power grab". **Someone** must be chosen to be the new VP. If 51 Senators cannot agree, then the sitting VP must break the tie.

   In any case, that is how the Constitution, as currently amended, now reads. It could be changed, the process for electing the VP was changed once, by the 12th amendment. Whether it **should** be changed, to handle this case which has never yet occurred, is a matter of politics, not law.